# Connect to oracle from AWS Lambda using cx_oracle with SSL authentication

Tags: oracle, aws-lambda, cx-oracle

Connect to oracle from AWS Lambda using cx_oracle with SSL authentication.I have the certificates in s3 how to use them in connect string

Comment: How do other people/tools connect to that DB?

Comment: Its through the insecure port...we are trying with SSL for the first time